# Intel VT-X not found

Tags: android, intel, haxm

I have activated virtualization in BIOS. I even made sure by running Intel processor identification utility. but i get the following error when i try to install Intel HAXM.

[image]

How to overcome the error & install Intel HAXM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem.
Do u use avast antivirus?
If yes then you have to disable Hardware assisted virtualization in Settings->trobleshooting tab of avast.

If no then download this software from the link below.It will tell you whether the VT-x is enable or not.
http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalCPUID/index-e.html